# Add points to canvas in android without refreshing the whole canvas

Tags: android, canvas, view

Is there a way to update the path in a canvas without refreshing the whole canvas?
I want to update a path by adding a point every 100 milliseconds, and refreshing the whole canvas creates performance issues.

Comment: What is the canvas backed to-  a view?  Bitmap?  Other?  That makes a big difference.

Comment: If you want to add a new point, just increment a variable every one hundred ms that determines where the next point will be.

Comment: @GabeSechan It is backed to a view.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to partially draw a view. On draw draws the whole thing. What you could do is double buffering- draw to a bitmap backed canvas, then your on draw is just drawing that bitmap to the view. The cost of this is as in memory bitmap of the view. But it's generally a huge perf win, drawing a bitmap is fast and can be done in a background thread, and copying a bitmap isn't bad.